# Por que no se guarda como null mi dato si no digito ningún valor

Tags: java

una pregunta , aquí supuestamente estoy pidiendo datos por teclado , pero al momento que me piden los datos , yo presiono *enter* sin poner un valor , para que no guarde ningún valor y se guarde como nulo.
No se supone que en la ultima linea cuando muestro el valor de "titulo" debería aparecer como `null` en la pantalla  Pues solo me aparece vacío es decir no me muestra nada

```
public class Ejercicios {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    Cuenta cuenta_1 = new Cuenta();       
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre titular");
    String titulo;
    titulo = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println(titulo);
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: lo que se guarda es `""`,  una cadena vacía

Comment: si quieres que se guarde `null` deberías hacer `titulo = (titulo.isEmpty())?null:titulo;`

Comment: te va a aparecer null, cuando inicialices la variable titulo como null, pero al no hacerlo si le das enter ya estas guardando un dato ("")

Comment: Podrias ser un poco mas especifico bro jejejej soy nuevo en esto de la programación en java xdd

Comment: [Según la documentación, `nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) devuelve **el resto de la línea actual, excluyendo cualquier separador de línea al final**. Significa que cuando presionas Enter, se crea una cadena vacía, o sea, con el valor `""`. Digamos que cada línea de `Scanner` empieza así: `"\n"`, donde `\n` es el salto de línea, y `nextLine()` quita de esa cadena `\n` quedándote una cadena vacía. Por otro lado, no deberías intentar imprimir un valor `null`, tu código dará error si lo intentas.